Data is not getting inserted into proper partition
I have a table with proper partition.
Code snippet:
CREATE TABLE RSA_DBA.RSA_ADHOC_ACCT
(   
    RSA_ACCT_DTL_GID NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL, 
    EFF_DT DATE NOT NULL, 
    RSA_CMPSN_REC_GID NUMBER(12,0), 
    ACCT_ID NUMBER(12,0), 
    ACCT_CMPSN_AMT NUMBER(16,3), 
    INSRT_USER VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) DEFAULT USER NOT NULL, 
    INSRT_TS DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL, 
    UPDT_USER VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) DEFAULT USER NOT NULL, 
    UPDT_TS DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL, 
    PRCS_RUN_ID NUMBER(12,0), 
    SRC_TS DATE, 
    VLD_IND CHAR(1 BYTE), 

    CONSTRAINT PK_RSA_ADHOC_ACCT_DTL_AI 
        PRIMARY KEY (RSA_ACCT_DTL_GID, EFF_DT)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (EFF_DT) 
    PARTITION PTN_M20221201  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2023-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    PARTITION PTN_M20230101  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2023-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    PARTITION PTN_M20230201  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2023-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
     :
     :
     :
     PARTITION PTN_M20241001  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2024-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
     PARTITION PTN_M20241101  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2024-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
)

When I am trying to insert data, few data got inserted properly in respective partition while others didn't.
Sharing screenshot of data available data in table:
SQL:
select trunc(EFF_DT), count(ACCT_CMPSN_AMT) 
from RSA_DBA.RSA_ADHOC_ACCT
group by  trunc(EFF_DT)
order by 1;


Now we we look into table "dba_tab_partitions" to check if data are properly inserted I can see only 2 partition has proper data, highlighted.
SQL:
SELECT table_name, partition_name, num_rows
FROM dba_tab_partitions
WHERE table_name  like 'RSA_ADHOC_ACCT' and NUM_ROWS > 0
ORDER BY table_name, partition_name;


Please note: here I can see for other partition data is very huge. Can someone guide me - where can I fix this issue? It's a PROD issue.

Have you queried the actual partitions ? Use the "partition" clause in the select statement to limit the resultset to only records that are stored in a particular partition ? What you are showing just shows the amount of data in a partition, it doesn't show that data is in the wrong partition.

When checked issue found in "Gathering statistics". Since the data volume was high and hence oracle didn't performed proper partition maintenance.
when checked object_id of the inserted data with respect to eff_dt it was matching with the partion object_id value(obtained using dba_objects)
SQL:
select distinct substr(dbms_rowid.rowid_object(rowid),1,15) object_id , eff_dt
from RSA_ADHOC_ACCT;

Object_id obtained:

Thus just by executing below SQL, I was able to get these data reflected corresponding to partition.
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'RSA_DBA', tabname => RSA_ADHOC_ACCT, estimate_percent => 100);


Correct, you cannot rely on statistics as being accurate unless you gather with compute statistics immediately before. Stats are intended for the optimizer to get a good-enough idea of cardinality for its decision-making tree. It should only be used by Oracle internally for this purpose.
